# Main vertical scroll affects the scroll in a fixed div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a basic container with overflow-y and fixed to the bottom of the page.
My problem was that the main scroll of the page affected the containers scroll.
When the main scroll is at the top the chat scroll works fine, but when it is down at the bottom the chat scroll isn't working correctly.

Where is the error in my code?

```
<style>
.floatChat{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 95px;
    z-index: 1001;      
    height: 250px;           
    font-size: 12px;    
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;}
</style>

<div id="chatPanel"> <div class="floatChat">
         <div id="chat" class="col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width:250px;">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="height:30px; font-size:12px; border-color:#069;">
                <div class="panel-actions" style="height:30px;">
                    <div class="btn-group">                                          
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Practise"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-times btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Close" onclick="removeChatBox(index);"></i>
                    </div>                                                         
                </div>
                <div class="text-bold"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i> friendName </div>                                               
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body bg-inverse" style="height:210px;">
                <div style="height:190px; width:230px;">
                    <div id="mesContainer" style="overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; height:170px; word-wrap: break-word;">                                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer" style="padding:0px;">
                <div class="input-group input-group-in">
                    <input id="mes" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button id="send" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="sendChatMessage(friendId)";><i class="fa fa-share text-midnight"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>                 
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

`MesContainer` is the container of the message.

Comment: I can suggest you using this [usefull tool](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Found out that i had a style file with

**-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);**

defined in a class.

that did the whole problem.